# verify Dapr service invocation in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dapr

How can I write a unit test that verifies a Dapr service was invoked ([Service invocation](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/service-invocation/service-invocation-overview/)) when I'm using the `InvokeMethodAsync` method that takes in the `HttpMethod`, `appId`, `methodName`, `TRequest data` and `CancellationToken` ([the one used in this sample?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/getting-started#:%7E:text=open%20the%20index.cshtml.cs%20file%20in%20the%20pages%20folder%2C%20and%20replace%20its%20contents%20with%20the%20following%20code%3A))

*usage:*

```cs
await _daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(
            HttpMethod.Get, "MyBackEnd", "weatherforecast");
```

*test code:*

```cs
[TestMethod("MyFrontEnd should call weatherforecast endpoint on MyBackEnd service")]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    //arrange
    var daprClientMock = new Mock<DaprClient>();
    var weatherForecastController = 
        new WeatherForecastController(Mock.Of<ILogger<weatherForecastController>>(), daprClientMock.Object);

    //act
    var forecasts = await weatherForecastController.Get();

    //assert
    daprClientMock.Verify(daprClient =>
        daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(HttpMethod.Get
            , "MyBackEnd", "weatherforecast", default(CancellationToken))
        , Times.Once());
}
```

*library method source:*

```cs
public abstract class DaprClient : IDisposable
{
    //snippet of method I'm invoking
    public Task<TResponse> InvokeMethodAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(HttpMethod httpMethod
        , string appId, string methodName, TRequest data
        , CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = CreateInvokeMethodRequest(httpMethod
            , appId, methodName, data);
        return InvokeMethodAsync<TResponse>(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/src/Dapr.Client/DaprClient.cs#L381)

*error message when running my current test:*

> Test method MyFrontEnd.BlahControllerTests.TestMethod1 threw exception:
> System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: daprClient => daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync<IEnumerable>(HttpMethod.Get, "MyBackEnd", "weatherforecast", CancellationToken)
> Non-overridable members (here: DaprClient.InvokeMethodAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

---

#### My research/thinking

This is something I would want to test right?  Service invocation verification is a valid use case when unit testing, right?

Assuming that is correct, the [DaprClient](https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/src/Dapr.Client/DaprClient.cs) is an `abstract` class (ok, I guess that works) but the method I'm calling isn't.

I'm guessing I have to call the abstract version of [InvokeMethodAsync](https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/291f73758d9231e72198c124c6286643fc8795df/src/Dapr.Client/DaprClient.cs#L356) then?  And then I should create my own method that does what the above code is doing so I don't create any DRY violations ⚠️?

But when I look into [CreateInvokeMethodRequest](https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/src/Dapr.Client/DaprClient.cs#L307), that's `abstract` so how the heck does this work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [@halspang](https://github.com/halspang)'s [sample here](https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/issues/774#issuecomment-966721169), I've derived the following pattern:

```cs
[TestMethod("mock dapr service invocation")]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    //arrange
    var daprClient = new Mock<DaprClient>();
    var exampleService = new ExampleService(daprClient.Object);

    var serviceInvocationRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();

    //normal setup: when called, return
    //this mocked resopnse;
    //BUT we have to make sure it's
    //the same request we're mocking
    //next in the CreateInvokeMethodRequest
    //setup.
    daprClient.Setup(d => d.InvokeMethodAsync<Customer>(serviceInvocationRequest
        , It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new Customer
        {
            Name = "Mike D."
        });

    //b/c the DaprClient follows a pattern like
    //this: calling the more speficic flavors
    //of InvokeMethodAsync will call
    //the abstract CreateInvokeMethodRequest
    //method and then call the abstract
    //InvokeMethodAsync method,
    //we can use the knowledge of the internal
    //workings of the DaprClient (which
    //seems like code smell to me)
    //to indirectly verify the args
    //we used to call invoke the
    //the other service.
    //public Task InvokeMethodAsync(
    //    string appId,
    //    string methodName,
    //    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    //{
    //    var request = CreateInvokeMethodRequest(appId, methodName);
    //    return InvokeMethodAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    //}
    daprClient.Setup(d => d.CreateInvokeMethodRequest(
        HttpMethod.Get, "my-cool-app", "customer"))
        .Returns(serviceInvocationRequest);

    var actual = await exampleService.IsTheCustomerNameMikeD();

    //assert
    actual.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

[full project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/tree/master/Dapr%20unit%20testing%20research/Dapr%20unit%20test%20prj%201)

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts seem absolutely reasonable to me.

The biggest challenge for me with these kind of test issues is to not couple the tests of **my** code too much to a certain implementation detail (e. g. Dapr). Therefore I typically use one of the following patterns.

## 1. Humble Object Pattern

Create another level of abstraction, e. g. `IWeatherForecastRepository` and move the Dapr client into the implementation.

```cs
public interface IWeatherForecastRepository
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetForecastsAsync();
}

internal class WeatherForecastRepository
{
    public WeatherForecastRepository(DaprClient daprClient) => _daprClient = daprClient;

    public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetForecastsAsync() =>
        _daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(HttpMethod.Get, "MyBackEnd", "weatherforecast");
}
```

Then the test will look like this:

```cs
[TestMethod("MyFrontEnd should call weatherforecast endpoint on MyBackEnd service")]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    //arrange
    var weatherForecastRepositoryMock = new Mock<IWeatherForecastRepository>();
    var weatherForecastController = 
        new WeatherForecastController(Mock.Of<ILogger<weatherForecastController>>(), weatherForecastRepositoryMock.Object);

    //act
    var forecasts = await weatherForecastController.Get();

    //assert
    weatherForecastRepositoryMock.Verify(repo =>
        repo.GetForecastsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(), Times.Once());
}
```

I like this approach because the code typically becomes more readable/comprehensible. It feels much more natural to me reading something like `GetForecastsAsync` than `InvokeMethodAsync`.

## 2. Custom test implementation

If the first approach is not acceptable or does not appeal, I create a custom implementation of `DaprClient` for the test:

```cs
[TestMethod("MyFrontEnd should call weatherforecast endpoint on MyBackEnd service")]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    //arrange
    var customDaprClient = CustomDaprClient();
    var weatherForecastController = 
        new WeatherForecastController(Mock.Of<ILogger<weatherForecastController>>(), customDaprClient);

    //act
    var forecasts = await weatherForecastController.Get();

    //assert
    customDaprClient.InvokeMethodAsyncWasCalled.Should().BeTrue();
}

private class CustomDaprClient : DaprClient
{
    public bool InvokeMethodAsyncWasCalled { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> ArgsOfInvokeMethodAsync { get; private set; }

    public new T InvokeMethodAsync<T>(params object[] args)
    {
        InvokeMethodAsyncWasCalled = true;
        ArgsOfInvokeMethodAsync = args.ToList();

        return base.InvokeMethodAsync<T>(args);
    ]
}
```

This approach can become messy quite fast, depending on the number of methods and arguments. Therefore I try to avoid it as much as possible, but sometimes it's better than no tests at all.

Comment: Hi @mu88 - thanks for the response!  I think it's best to [submit two answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable) therefore they can be upvoted/comment independently.